API Fetch Request Works on Desktop but Not on Mobile – CORS or HTTPS Issue?
I'm building a Svelte app that fetches random quotes from an API (https://zenquotes.io/api/random). The app works perfectly on desktop browsers but fails to fetch data on mobile devices (both locally and when deployed on Netlify).
Here's What I've Tried:

Tested the API directly in both desktop and mobile browsers – it works fine in both.

Confirmed the app works locally on http://localhost:5173 for desktop, but mobile devices fail to fetch data (even on the same local network).

Deployed the app on Netlify using HTTPS – still doesn't work on mobile. I also ensured the Netlify build settings were correct.

Tried debugging with Chrome DevTools on mobile. I noticed a CORS error and net::ERR_FAILED when fetching the API.

Considered a proxy to bypass CORS, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Switched to different free quote APIs, including zenquotes.io, but the issue persists on mobile devices.


async function fetchQuote() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://zenquotes.io/api/random', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch quote');
    const data = await response.json();
    quote = data[0].q;
    author = data[0].a;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Fetch Error:', error);
    quote = 'Could not fetch a quote.';
    author = 'Unknown';
  }
}


How can I ensure my fetch requests work on mobile devices? Is there a known issue with mobile CORS policies or SSL validation, and what would be the best way to resolve this?

Transcribe the CORS error.  Also, because it hurts my eyes so much:  Don't do an IF to throw an error, to then catch it.  Just do if (!response.ok) { console.error(); } else { }.
